# Beats can't send data suddenly to ES with errors pop up

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using ES 5.0, Kibana 5.0 alpha4 and various beats to send data to ES. Everything runs fine and smooth at first. However, after a day, the beats suddenly cannot send the beats to the ES. I have been using different beats, including winlogbeat, metribeats, etc. All of them suddenly stop working.

Error is as shown

```
2016/07/16 15:22:15.259659 single.go:130: INFO Connecting error publishing events (retrying): 401 Unauthorized
2016/07/16 15:22:15.259695 single.go:145: INFO send fail
```

What would be the issue?

Comment: you might have installed or enabled any type of authentication on Elasticsearch server like `Shield`.

Comment: Yes, I have installed x-pack, but it sends out data smooth originally, and just suddenly comes with error. How can I enable beats to send data to ES?

Comment: If you have enabled username and password then you can give them in beats configuration as mentioned in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/winlogbeat/current/securing-communication-elasticsearch.html

Comment: Thanks. It works smooth now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enabled authentication on Elasticsearch server like `Shield(Security)`.

Put this in `Beats` configuration

```
elasticsearch:
  username: `Your username here`
  password: `Your password here`
  protocol: `Choose your protocol here (http or https)`
  hosts: `Array of Elasticsearch hosts like ["elasticsearch.example.com:9200"] `
```